# List of ROMs for HTC Flyer

Tags: rom, htc-flyer

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/17152/where-can-i-find-stock-or-custom-roms-for-my-android-device)

I've just received an HTC Flyer which I intend on rooting and putting a custom ROM on.  Normally I would look at CyanogenMod, but it seems that there isn't a port for the Flyer, so I was wondering if there is any resource where I can see a list of ROMs available for a given device?

Comment: This is either going to be based on opinion or also sort of a "shopping recommendation", which are off topic here. Please see the [faq](http://android.stackexchange.com/faq)

Comment: have edited question

Comment: [Where can I find stock or custom ROMs for my Android device?](http://android.stackexchange.com/q/17152/981)